# Configure a field with a Widget Type on a Data Type using C#

Tags: c#, c1-cms

I'm currently working on a new site based on Composite C1 5.0
I'm looking at having as much as possible regarding Data Types in c# code, but I can't find how to associate a Widget Type for a field in C#. I've looked through the [Composite C1 documentation regarding Data types](http://docs.composite.net/Data/Defining-Data-IData-types-in-C1-using-C) but can't find if this is possible.
I can however configure a widget type in Composite, but then I'm dependant on the generated Xml file holding this information.

Is this possible?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the FormRenderingProfileAttribute attribute to your DataType Property like this

```
[FormRenderingProfile(Label = "Title", HelpText = "Help for title", WidgetFunctionMarkup = "...")]
string Title { get; set; }
```

https://github.com/Orckestra/C1-CMS/blob/master/Composite/Data/FormRenderingProfileAttribute.cs

Assign this to properties on your IData interfaces to control how a data field whould be viewed and edited in a form view.